# How to substract the two lists which one list contain the value from a resample method and another list is contain normal values in dataframe?

Tags: python

my first dataframe (`df1`) looks like this

```
PL_resample
2018-01-01 00:00:00    282.533333
2018-01-01 00:15:00    295.400000
2018-01-01 00:30:00    162.933333
2018-01-01 00:45:00    141.200000
2018-01-01 01:00:00    186.066667
2018-01-01 01:15:00     61.600000
2018-01-01 01:30:00    104.933333
2018-01-01 01:45:00    316.733333
2018-01-01 02:00:00    294.733333
2018-01-01 02:15:00    207.533333
2018-01-01 02:30:00    256.600000
Freq: 15T, Name: PL, dtype: float64
```

And the second dataframe (`df2`) looks like this

```
    Ppv
0   128.34916494383114
1   126.58570002025442
2   123.44801805283744
3   117.44595663399937
4   107.43012022255779
5   88.72558810855682
6   71.47247359312877
7   106.02608144119506
8   105.98001538360776
9   106.19784959216611
10  106.29336647920698
11  106.38710980808393
12  106.51127019884727
```

With this programm code

```
rest_list = df2.Ppv.iloc[0:11] - df1.PL.iloc[0:11]
```

I got the this results below which is wrong.

```
2018-01-01 00:00:00   NaN
2018-01-01 00:15:00   NaN
2018-01-01 00:30:00   NaN
2018-01-01 00:45:00   NaN
2018-01-01 01:00:00   NaN
2018-01-01 01:15:00   NaN
2018-01-01 01:30:00   NaN
2018-01-01 01:45:00   NaN
2018-01-01 02:00:00   NaN
2018-01-01 02:15:00   NaN
2018-01-01 02:30:00   NaN
0                     NaN
1                     NaN
2                     NaN
3                     NaN
4                     NaN
5                     NaN
6                     NaN
7                     NaN
8                     NaN
9                     NaN
10                    NaN
```

How could I fix them?

Comment: hi @ChirayuBall, your code and the dataframes' column names do not match. And is `PL_resample` index of the first dataframe?

Comment: Im not sure if resample is an index or not? How can I check that? If I print PL_resample in the console. It gives me this: Freq: 15T, Name: PL, dtype: float64

Comment: `df1` is a `pd.Series` now not a dataframe so ignore my previous comment. You can try `df2.Ppv.iloc[:11] - df1.PL.iloc[:11].to_numpy()` for subtraction. Since indices do not match you get `NaN`s so we subtract when one of them is numpy array.

Comment: ...or if you want to keep the other one's index at the end, `to_numpy` on that one: `df2.Ppv.iloc[:11].to_numpy() - df1.PL.iloc[:11]`.

Comment: That is great solution, thank you very much!

Comment: glad it worked! do you mind if I post it as an answer below?

Comment: Actually, df1 is a Dataframe, isn't it?

Comment: Of course! Please do it.

Comment: yes `df1` is indeed a DataFrame. But in the question you said *my first dataframe (df1) looks like this* and what comes after is actually a `pd.Series` so that means you actually posted `df1.PL` instead of whole `df1` and I got confused sorry `:)`. In short, yes it is a frame, but `df1.PL` is a column of it and it is a series.

Comment: Im still not really understand. Why we just need to add to_numpy() after the series and it works?

Comment: Pandas data structures have *index* labels and *column* labels. When you subtract two series as in your question, it first looks at the *indices* and finds the intersection and puts the difference there. If it cannot find an intersection (as in your case), it concatanates all the indices together and puts `NaN` as the value in the result (as in your case). When we say `to_numpy()` however, we make one of them a numpy array which has no concept of index labels or column labels; it's only numbers! So, when a numpy array is subtracted from a pandas series, no index matching is attempted at all.

Comment: ...and the corresponding values are subtracted as expected. In the result, series' index is kept.

Comment: Lastly, if you put `to_numpy` to *both* of them, you will see only numbers at the end, and no index whatsoever will be present.

Comment: Thanks for your clearly explanation. I have another question relating to this code df2.Ppv.iloc[:11].to_numpy() - df1.PL.iloc[:11]. I would like to print the index of it for example 2018-01-01,  -154.18416838950222. How could I realise this?

Comment: I didn't understand. Only the first index or all the values?

Comment: With this code,  I would get the index and the value which is greater than the 'cap'. Instead of x index, I would to get the datetime object: 
total = 0
cap = -400
for x in range(len(rest_list) - 1, - 1, -1):  
      total += rest_list[x]
    if total >= cap:
        print(x, total)
        break

Comment: With that `x` you can index into `df1`'s index: `df1.index[x]` to get the timestamp

Comment: glad to be of help! If you wish, you might consider [accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) the answer below to signal others that the issue is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
df2.Ppv.iloc[:11] - df1.PL.iloc[:11].to_numpy()
```

for subtraction. Since indices do not match you get `NaN`s so we subtract when one of them is numpy array.

...or if you want to keep the other one's index at the end, `to_numpy` on that one:

```
df2.Ppv.iloc[:11].to_numpy() - df1.PL.iloc[:11]
```